# Why is our product table empty?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

A friend and I are working on a project. When we run the code there is no data on the product page. All the products are missing.

We have created a `DbInitializer.cs` file with data on different products. All the other data from the file appears but the product data does not.

```
 var products = new Product[]
           {
                new Product{ProductID=1050,ProductName="CD-ORD",Price=100,
                 MarketID = markets.Single( s => s.Name == "england").MarketID
                },


                new Product{ProductID=4022,ProductName="Intowords",Price=100,
                 MarketID = markets.Single( s => s.Name == "england").MarketID
                },
                new Product{ProductID=4041,ProductName="Reading Pen",Price=100,
                 MarketID = markets.Single( s => s.Name == "england").MarketID
                },
                new Product{ProductID=1045,ProductName="CD-ORD and Intowords",Price=150,
                 MarketID = markets.Single( s => s.Name == "england").MarketID
                },
                new Product{ProductID=3141,ProductName="CD-ORD and Reading Pen",Price=150,
                 MarketID = markets.Single( s => s.Name == "england").MarketID
                },
                new Product{ProductID=2021,ProductName="Intowords and Reading Pen",Price=150,
                 MarketID = markets.Single( s => s.Name == "england").MarketID
                },
                new Product{ProductID=2042,ProductName="Intowords",Price=100,
                 MarketID = markets.Single( s => s.Name == "england").MarketID
                },
                new Product{ProductID=2042,ProductName="CD-ORD and Intowords and Reading Pen",Price=175,
                 MarketID = markets.Single( s => s.Name == "england").MarketID
                },
           };
            foreach (Product p in products)
            {
                context.Products.Add(p);
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
```

After we update the database we expect data to go into the Product table and show on the website when we run the code but it does not. Here is a link to the entire project: https://github.com/ahma0307/VitekSite6

Help would be really appreciated. We have been looking at this for hours.

EDIT: The following code shows my Object mapping I think

```
public class BusinessContext : DbContext
    {
        public BusinessContext (DbContextOptions<BusinessContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Subscription> Subscriptions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Market> Markets { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProductGuide> ProductGuides { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CountryAssignment> CountryAssignments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProductAssignment> ProductAssignments { get; set; }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().ToTable("Product");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Subscription>().ToTable("Subscription");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().ToTable("Customer");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Market>().ToTable("Market");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ProductGuide>().ToTable("ProductGuide");
            modelBuilder.Entity<CountryAssignment>().ToTable("CountryAssignment");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ProductAssignment>().ToTable("ProductAssignment");

            modelBuilder.Entity<ProductAssignment>()
                .HasKey(pa => new { pa.ProductID, pa.ProductGuideID });
        }

        public DbSet<VitekSite.Models.Customer> Customer { get; set; }
    }
```

EDIT 2: I changed the ProductID's so they are different and capitalized all s.Name

```
 var products = new Product[]
       {
            new Product{ProductID=1050,ProductName="CD-ORD",Price=100,
             MarketID = markets.Single( s => s.Name == "England").MarketID
            },
            new Product{ProductID=4022,ProductName="Intowords",Price=100,
             MarketID = markets.Single( s => s.Name == "England").MarketID
            },
            new Product{ProductID=4041,ProductName="Reading Pen",Price=100,
             MarketID = markets.Single( s => s.Name == "Danmark").MarketID
            },
            new Product{ProductID=1045,ProductName="CD-ORD and Intowords",Price=150,
             MarketID = markets.Single( s => s.Name == "Sverige").MarketID
            },
            new Product{ProductID=3141,ProductName="CD-ORD and Reading Pen",Price=150,
             MarketID = markets.Single( s => s.Name == "Norge").MarketID
            },
            new Product{ProductID=2021,ProductName="Intowords and Reading Pen",Price=150,
             MarketID = markets.Single( s => s.Name == "Danmark").MarketID
            },
            new Product{ProductID=2042,ProductName="Intowords",Price=100,
             MarketID = markets.Single( s => s.Name == "Norge").MarketID
            },
       };
```

Comment: _"there is no data on the product page"_ - but is there product data in the database?

Comment: This could mean a few different issues. First, as @stuartd mentioned, can you `Select` the data in the SQL Server database after you load the project? Second, could the issue be in the page that shows the data?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  First, please post the code to relevant areas and not a link to your entire project. Second, for this code, instead of doing the foreach loop, do context.AddRange(products);

Comment: You will have to include the object-mapping too, and make sure that the `SaveChanges()` isn't silently failing.

Comment: @suartd No there is no product data in the database which I don't understand because there is Customer data in the Customer table

Comment: @Eric Wu I can view the data via visual studios SQL Server Object Explorer and there is no data in the product table which is in the SQL Database. With regards to where the issue is I am really not sure but I think it has something to do with the SQL database..perhaps something with me not dropping or updating the database or perhaps something to do with adding migrations in the PMC. I Don't know.

Comment: @HazardousGlitch Thankyou for the welcome. I don't know which part of the code is relevant and should be posted :/. I have outcommented the foreach loop and done context.AddRange(products); instead. Nice change.

Comment: @EzLo How do I include the object-mapping? What is it? And how do I make sure SaveChanges() is not silently failing?

Comment: @EzLo I have edited the post to include the code for what I think is the object mapping..

Comment: I am still stuck with the issue so if anyone has some clarification it would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the database using Microsoft SQL Studio or similar program to see if it has any records for the table?

Comment: @HazardousGlitch I have only viewed data in the tables via the SSOX in Visual Studio 2019. I have just downloaded SSMS now and am about to check it out.

Comment: I have updated the code on github with the changes I have made after reading Renas answer, so the problems mentioned by Rena should be solved now but my product table is still empty.

Comment: Misplaced comma after last product in array?

Comment: @Arvo I don't think so..all the commas seem fine. I just tried to remove the last comma to see if there would be any difference and there isn't. So I just added it back and Microsoft uses the comma after the last product in their documentation.

Comment: Well, MS can have errors too - currently you have last element of array undefined or so. Looks like this doesn't matter. Another thing - I can't see your SQL table creation script; if your ProductID happens to be an identity field, then you can't set its value this way. If you omit ProductIDs, what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you have added two products with the same id.And be sure that `s.Name == "England"` not `s.Name == "england"`

To fix it,change:

```
new Product{ProductID=2042,ProductName="CD-ORD and Intowords and Reading Pen",Price=175,
             MarketID = markets.Single( s => s.Name == "England").MarketID
            },
```

to:

```
new Product{ProductID=2043,ProductName="CD-ORD and Intowords and Reading Pen",Price=175,
             MarketID = markets.Single( s => s.Name == "England").MarketID
            },
```

**UPDATE：**
`Product`'s MarketID should exsit in `Market`.You do not have an object with `Name=Norge` in `Market`.

To fix it,change:

```
new Product{ProductID=3141,ProductName="CD-ORD and Reading Pen",Price=150,
             MarketID = markets.Single( s => s.Name == "Norge").MarketID
            },              
            new Product{ProductID=2042,ProductName="Intowords",Price=100,
             MarketID = markets.Single( s => s.Name == "Norge").MarketID
            },
```

To:

```
new Product{ProductID=3141,ProductName="CD-ORD and Reading Pen",Price=150,
             MarketID = markets.Single( s => s.Name == "Danmark").MarketID
            },              
            new Product{ProductID=2042,ProductName="Intowords",Price=100,
             MarketID = markets.Single( s => s.Name == "Danmark").MarketID
            },
```

The other workaround is that you could add an record in Market:

```
new Market { Name = "Norge",   Budget = 200000,
                StartDate = DateTime.Parse("2007-09-01"),
                ProductGuideID  = productGuides.Single( pg => pg.LastName == "Kapoor").ID }
```

Comment: Thankyou. I have updated the original post with EDIT 2 which shows the changes you mentioned. My ProductID's are now different and all s.Name start with a capital letter. But my product table in my Database is still empty and as a result when I run the debugger the product view is empty as well.

Comment: After you change the code,please be sure that delete the database and use the command `update-database` again to run the project.

Comment: Answer is accepted it worked. Thank you very much. We spent around 8 hours trying to fix it.